# Windows Scheduler: run on login

Tags: scheduled-task, windows-server-2003-r2

I would like to use Windows Schedule to schedule a task to run on login by any user. This is on Server 2003-R2.

It would run a Powershell that brings up an alert that the OS is end of life.

How can this be done? I remember seeing a way to do this as a scheduled task, but cannot find it in the GUI.

Comment: Hmmm. What's the point of doing this? Who are you alerting?

Comment: @joeqwerty All and any users who use the server to run Bostonworkstation Scripts on this device, as they will have to move their script to a new server

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT there's no such option (in 2003 servers).
The closest thing is running the task when the creating user is logged in.

You better use the Run reg key (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run).